# Is there a way to retrieve any data from the context my task was created on a delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, urlsession

I'm creating a task to download an image in the background inside a function and I have a `notification` object in the same context. I want to retrieve this `notification` object when the delegate `didFinishDownloadingToURL` is called. Is there any way I can do this?

I create a task like this:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"imageDownloadSession"];
[sessionConfig setDiscretionary:YES];
[sessionConfig setSessionSendsLaunchEvents:YES];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *getImageTask = [session downloadTaskWithURL:notification.imageRemoteURL];
```

And this is my delegate:

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
       downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
       didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {

    // I want to access the notification object here

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply store in the notification in a property in the class that you are using as NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate. So when downloadTaskWithURL is called you can access that property.
Alternatively you can create an other class that holds the notification as an instance property and acts as the delegate. An if you have multiple download tasks you can keep them in an array.

For example:

```
...
self.downloadDelegate = [[SessionDownloadDelegate alloc] init];
downloadDelegate.notification = notification

//Now use the downloadDelegate instead of self
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:downloadDelegate delegateQueue:nil];
...

@interface SessionDownloadDelegate: NSObject<NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate>
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject *notification;
@end

@implementation SessionDownloadDelegate
- (void)URLSession:(nonnull NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(nonnull NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(nonnull NSURL *)location {
//    access the notification object
//    self.notification
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I had this solution in mind but I was thinking if there could be a way to retrieve some data from some parameter in the delegate.